# Request Picture In Picture on scroll chrome

Tags: javascript, picture-in-picture

I want to use chrome's PIP when video is out of viewport by using scroll event listener. Chrome gives this error:

> Must be handling a user gesture to request picture in picture.

Can someone confirm if scroll is a user gesture or not? If it is why this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of events that can trigger "*by user activation*" as [defined by the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation):

> - change
> - click
> - contextmenu
> - dblclick
> - mouseup
> - pointerup
> - reset
> - submit
> - touchend

*scroll* is not there, and since the step *.6* of the [*Request Picture-in-Picture* algorithm](https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#request-pip) explicitly asks that

> If the algorithm is not triggered by [user activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation), throw a [NotAllowedError](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#notallowederror) and abort these steps.

you won't be able to request PiP through this event.

---

In your position, I would reconsider the need for PiP and check if a fixed positioned <video> can't do the trick instead.